# В чем смысл записи select 1%2?

Tags: sql

В чем смысл записи select 1%2 ?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=select+1%252&oq=select+1%252&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 1):

SELECT выражение позволяет выбрать данные из таблицы или рассчитать определённое значение (в данном случае второе)

Выражение 1 % 2 возвращает остаток деления 1 на 2 с результатом 1 (если попробовать 2%2, получим 0, ибо 2 делиться на 2 нацело)

Answer (score 1):

Здравствуй!

**SELECT** - это начало выполнения какой-то операции. SQL-запросы позволяют выполнять арифметические операции:

```
SELECT 1+1; 
//2
SELECT 1-1;
//0
SELECT 1*2;
//2
SELECT 2/2;
//1
SELECT 1%2; - наш вариант, который мы подробно сейчас разберем с точки зрения алгебры.
//1
SELECT 2^3; - возведение в степень
//8
```

Существуют еще несколько арифметический операций, с ними ты можешь ознакомиться в официальных источниках.

> SELECT 1%2;

Данная арифметическая операция - это остаток от деления. Что это значит?
Если мы поделим 5 на 5, то получим 1 и **остаток 0**.
Если мы поделим 5 на 7, то получим 1 и **остаток 2**.

Так вот, при обычном делении мы получим первый результат, а при делении с остатком мы получим второй результат - сам остаток от деления.

В нашем случае будет выведено 1, так как при делении 1 на 2 в результате будет целое число 0 и остаток 1.

Успеха в дальнейшем!